# Why the "gap" property working on flexbox and is it right to use it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was trying to make some gap between my content like "price:" "20$" I wanted to make a gap between 20$ and price , but I was using flexbox , suddenly I tried "gap" property which is for grid and it worked !

why ? and am I did right thing with doing it?

Comment: Yeah that's perfect. You can use `gap` to add some space between `flex-items`

Comment: Yes it is new flex property. can be applied to both `display:flex` and `display:grid` containers

Comment: @decpk thanks , I didn't know that it can work on flex

Comment: @GulamHussain Thanks for comment , I didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly fine to use `gap` with flexbox. (May not work with ie11 though)
Works with `display: flex`, `display: grid` and `column-count:`  elements.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#propdef-gap

> Applies to:   multi-column containers, flex containers, grid containers

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2022:**

Its supported in all major browsers! (IE is still out of the party though)

Reference: https://caniuse.com/?search=gap